# Interface method call error: method is unknown or PROTECTED or PRIVATE

Tags: oop, interface, abap

I'm looking at the following example, published on the [ABAP Keyword Documentation, page INTERFACE](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_750_index_htm/7.50/en-US/abapinterface_definition.htm). My changes are just additional lines: the `REPORT` statement and the statements beginning with `START-OF-SELECTION`.

Checking this code on an SAP system gives

> Method "M1(" is unknown or PROTECTED or PRIVATE.

But isn't all defined and public? I wrote similar code, just without the interface and check works fine.

```
REPORT ZUTEST2.

INTERFACE i1.
  DATA    a1 TYPE string.
  METHODS m1.
  EVENTS  e1 EXPORTING value(p1) TYPE string.
ENDINTERFACE.

CLASS c1 DEFINITION.
  PUBLIC SECTION.
    INTERFACES i1.
ENDCLASS.

CLASS c1 IMPLEMENTATION.
  METHOD i1~m1.
    RAISE EVENT i1~e1 EXPORTING p1 = i1~a1.
  ENDMETHOD.
ENDCLASS.

START-OF-SELECTION.

data r type ref to c1.
create object r.
call method r->m1( ).
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, the method `m1` is defined in the interface `i1`.

You should call like below

```
CALL METHOD r->i1~m1( ).
```

If you want to call the method of your class, you may define an **`ALIASES`** in your class.

```
CLASS c1 DEFINITION.
  PUBLIC SECTION.
  INTERFACES i1.
  ALIASES m1
    FOR i1~m1 .
ENDCLASS.
```

Then you call

```
call method r->m1( ).
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: That's correct, thanks. But that information is missing in the SAP online help, at least in the pages I'm looking at.

Comment: @UlrichScholz yes you are right. It happens sometimes I guess.  :)

Comment: The information is there: https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_750_index_htm/7.50/en-US/abapinterfaces_class.htm says "An interface component called comp has the name intf~comp in the class, where intf is the name of the interface and the character ~ is the interface component selector." The `ALIASES` statement has its own article https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_750_index_htm/7.50/en-US/abapaliases.htm with an example.

Answer (score 3):

Your class construction is wrong and should be:

```
data: r type ref to i1.
create object r type c1.
call method r->m1( ).
```

Comment: You are right: I copied it from SAP Help. But I said so right away. I'm surprised you're surprised :-)

Comment: Your example is a third solution, besides the two given by Haojie. BTW, there is a space missing between the brackets

Comment: sorry, it is corrected now :) I just looked at the code, my fault - you are right. you mentioned it. during analyzing I found exact this code (which is not a problem for me, just for the moment surprised) 

does it work? please accept the answer, if yes.

Comment: Though Haojie's answer (keep the `r type ref to c1` and define an alias to avoid the `i1~`) is also right, this one is the better solution from object orientation point of view.